# PHP Headers and another server

Tags: c#, php, single-sign-on

Ill try to explain this as best I can.

I have two web servers. Server A will have a link (or form post?) to Server B. When a user clicks the link on Server A I need to send two headers "Cookie: Username=jdoe" and "Cooke: Password=12341234". Then display the page from Server B to the user. Server B is already configured to look at the header request(?) and grab the username/password and then do stuff with it. I cannot get figure out how to get the request from A to B on behalf of the user an with custom cookie headers then back to the user. Can anyone help?

Background: This is a for a SSO implemtnation that we already have working using a Juniper SA400 that im guessing acts as a proxy of some sort. We are trying to replicate this functionality without using the SA box. Server B is an ASPX server that again, is already setup to look at the headers and it works.

Comment: If it's possible to use a form post, can't you simply add hidden fields instead of header values and read these (maybe encrypted)?

Comment: No, server B is configured to read Headers, specifically Cookie:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't server A act as a proxy?

```
User ----> Server A
           Server A ----> Server B
           Server A <---- Server B
User <---- Server A
```

User sends the form data to server A, server A (now acting as a client, for example with cURL or System.Net or whatever is available in your platform for that end) sends the headers to server B, which replies back to server A. Finally server A sends the response received from server B (raw or processed, depending on the exact needs) back to the user.

Comment: Ok so your suggesting i Google PHP cURL proxy and that should be good?  On the screen it looks like the only way it can happen, now i just need to piece together all the parts to make a proxy server now.